# Copy to and delete from matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

Not sure even if this question stands valid. But better ask.

Suppose we have two matrices in MATLAB of size (n,1) and (m,1) and we want to copy certain rows from matrix A to matrix B on a condition.

e.g. if value A(i,1) is less or equal to X

And later delete those rows from source matrix i.e. matrix A

Example:

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

B = [8, 9]

copy all values which are less than or equal to 4 from A to B, and delete from A
Matrices becomes

A = [5, 6]

B = [8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a logical matrix to identify the items:

```
mask = (A <= 4);
B = [B A(mask)];
A(mask) = [];
```

Comment: Bingo, worked like a charm. Fast and pretty approach. Honestly, I didn't know about the use of mask.

Comment: @Indigo: `mask` is a variable name, it's just storing the logical matrix created by the matrix comparison.

Comment: yes indeed true, logical matrix. wrong choice of words. Thanks :-)